# Flash message method doesn't handle HTML correct, the deprecated version of the method works as expected. Why?

Tags: magento2

I tried below code

```
$this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
   __('Hi you logged in successfully to your account. Take a look in your <a href="%1">dashboard</a>', $link)
);
```

This doesn't work, it results in the browser showing the HTML as text:

```
Hi you logged in successfully to your account. Take a look in your <a href="%1">dashboard</a>
```

The below  one on the other hand does work, but the method is deprecated according to the class method comments `Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` and it reffers to `addNoticeMessage` that's why I tried that method in the first place.

```
$this->messageManager->addNotice(
   __('Hi you logged in successfully to your account. Take a look in your <a href="%1">dashboard</a>', $link)
);
```

Why is that? And how can I fix it?